# AudioFileCreateWithURL failed,return -50

Tags: ios, core-audio

```
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;
    //
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.aif"]];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:databasePath];
    //
    AudioStreamBasicDescription asbd;
    memset(&asbd, 0, sizeof(asbd));
    asbd.mSampleRate = 44100;
    asbd.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    asbd.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsBigEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
    asbd.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
    asbd.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    asbd.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
    asbd.mBytesPerFrame = 2;
    asbd.mBytesPerPacket = 2;
    //
    AudioFileID audioFile;
    OSStatus audioErr = noErr;
    audioErr = AudioFileCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)fileURL,
                                      kAudioFileAIFFType,
                                      &asbd,
                                      kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile,
                                      &audioFile);
    NSLog(@"%ld",audioErr);
```

I run the code by iphone simulator,the log print is -50,I looked up the apple's doc,but can't find error code -50,I don't know what's the meaning of "-50",so what's the problem?and where can I get the error code?thank you.

update:I changed the code "`NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:databasePath];`"to "`CFURLRef fileURL = ( CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:databasePath];`",yes,it doesn't return error code -50,and return the success code 0,but serval seconds later,it will return error code 1886547263,I figured out it means "Failed to open or create audio file for writing".

Answer (score 2):

You can use `macerror` to look up some error codes:

```
$ macerror -50
Mac OS error -50 (paramErr): error in user parameter list
```

Answer (score 0):

-50 is `kAudio_ParamError`

I don't believe you can typecast an NSURL to a CFURL in the way you're doing. Here's how I do it (using your vars):

```
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pathForTheFile= [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.aif"];
CFURLRef fileURL = (__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathForTheFile];
```

Then, in your call to AudioFileCreateWithURL:

```
audioErr = AudioFileCreateWithURL(fileURL,
                                  kAudioFileAIFFType,
                                  &asbd,
                                  kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile,
                                  &audioFile);
```

Comment: `NSURL` and `CFURLRef` have been toll-free bridged since Mac OS X 10.0 (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html) so casting isn't the issue.

Comment: Good catch. Is it perhaps the *way* he's casting it though? When I tried what he did I'd get the same error but when using the __bridge on a CFURLRef var it works.